# How can you run a long calculation while updating a label displaying progress, without locking the UI?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
// does some long math calculation and stores informaiton in calc
calc = new Calculate(Dimensions, (current, total) =>
    {
        var percent = (int)(100 * current / total);

        // updates labels on the UI whilst the calculations run
        // this locks up the UI
        try { lbl_Progress.Text = $"{percent}%"; }
        catch { lbl_Progress.Text = "?%"; }
        finally { lbl_Progress.Refresh(); }
    });

// wait for the above code to finish
UpdateData(calc); // updates labels with now calculated information n calc
```

calc is a calculation that is being run, and depending on user input, can take from a few seconds to a few minutes. As you can see, I need to update a single label to display `percent`. Can someone explain how you can run this code, update the label, and not lock up the UI?

I know you can't update the main thread from another thread, so I have looked online, and have been referred to [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming), however, I haven't been able to figure out how to implement the code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] when asking a question. Nevertheless, this kind of question has been asked here a million times and has plenty of good answers.

Comment: Is this Winforms?  If so, use a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @BrianRogers is there any downsides to using a background worker?

Comment: Not that I know of; your use case is exactly what it was intended for.

Comment: @TimeTravelPenguin - Microsoft's Reactive Framework is a good choice for this kind of thing.